# Can you solve this Country puzzle?

Tags: knowledge, visual, sequence, flags

**Given this sequence of flags, which flag should replace the question mark? Explain.**

---

[image]

---

*Note: I added 'knowledge'-tag, but it's nothing complicated.*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the next flag in the sequence is

> [image]

Firstly, the countries, in order, are

> Cote d'Ivoire
>  Greece
>  Mauritius
>  Malaysia
>  Equatorial Guinea
>  Turkiye

Then we must look at

> Each countries [calling code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) which are, from left to right, (with small flags in brackets)
>  +225, (+30), +230, (+60), +240, (+90)
>  How do we interpret these numbers?
>  Well, the big flag at the top has a large circle in the middle which may represent a clock face so maybe numbers corresponding to bigger flags are **times**.
>  Similarly, the small flag has a small circle in the top right so maybe numbers corresponding to smaller flags represent **degrees**.
>  Indeed, if we consider the big number flags as times - **2:25, 2:30, 2:40** then the small flag numbers in between represent the degrees the minute hand moves between the times on a clock face. The next time is 90 degrees on from **2:40** and so must be **2:55**.
>  The country with calling code **255** is Tanzania - hence the next flag.

Comment: This is the correct answer, good job!

Comment: `small circle in the top right so maybe numbers corresponding to smaller flags represent degrees`.   I don't follow what a small circle has to do with degrees?

Comment: @BuhBuh For example 90°

Comment: Oh I see now.  `90°` has a little circle top right.  Thanks