# please Extend this list of Units

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence, sequence

##### Given the following list of four corresponding series of numbers, what would the fifth line look like?

---

- 1 : 1.4 / 3
- 2 : 3 / 2 | 1 : 2 / 6
- 2 : 3 / 2
- 1 : 2 / 3

---

*Hint 1: This puzzle was inspired by the prime number 119698.*

*Hint to Hint 1: The call is coming from inside the house, just nine doors down from this one.*

*Hint 2: The prime number might be flagged as both a bit 1337 and bit gangstah.*

Comment: 119698 prime?! That's a new one on me... :)

Comment: @Stiv Given how insanely good people here are at extracting really complex connections from nothing at all, I didn’t want to make the hint _too_ easy.

Comment: mysterious 119698 is even  in every base

Comment: @Jasen Oddly (!) enough, that doesn’t matter in the slightest. In fact, the hints aren’t mathematical at all. But the [tag:knowledge] tag applies to both the actual puzzle and the hints.

Comment: it's even in all bases due to the pattern of odd and even digits (not that I spotted that first)

Comment: @Jasen I don’t even understand what that means…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no other answers (or updates to Stiv’s answer) have appeared since March, I will fill in the blanks – with the note that Stiv came *very* close to the full solution.

Instead of posting the full logic from start to finish, I will refer to Stiv’s answer and only address the missed points:

#### Title clue

> There's another useful clue in the title too...
>
> > There are two capitalised letters in it - 'E' and 'U'. This means we are likely to need to think about **Eu**ropean flags in particular.

This is where things went slightly awry:

> The capitalisation implies that we need to think about **E**uropean **U**nion flags, not European flags – this is important, because some of the flags are actually *not* traditionally considered European.

#### Defining logic

> However, since I have not yet managed to disambiguate these, it is impossible to know what the intention for a 'fifth line' would be. One thing that may come into play here is...
>
> > ...differing statuses of [EU membership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlargement_of_the_European_Union), especially since (famously on all 3 counts) Kosovo is currently an applicant, Turkey's application is the subject of a high-profile freeze right now, and the UK is the only nation to have actually left the union. However, I'm not seeing it just yet...

This actually – probably coincidentally – links to the *exact* Wikipedia article that holds the answer:

> If you scroll down to the section [Historical enlargements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlargement_of_the_European_Union#Historical_enlargements), there is a table of countries which have historically *applied* to become a member of the EU. Ordering that table by submission date, with newest submissions on top, provides the basis of the data.
>
>  Given that none of the newest applicants have been accepted into the EU yet, their defining commonality here is that they are *not* EU members (indeed, Georgia is arguably not in Europe), but hoping to be so.

#### Correct solution

The correct values for the rows in the question are thus:

> **1 : 1.4 / 3**   :   Kosovo (submission date: 14 Dec 2022)
>
>  [image: Kosovan flag]
>
>  **2 : 3 / 2 | 1 : 2 / 6**   :   Georgia & Moldova (submission date: 3 March 2022)
>
>  [image: Georgian flag] [image: Moldovan flag]
>
>  **2 : 3 / 2**   :   Ukraine (submission date: 28 February 2022)
>
>  [image: Ukrainian flag]
>
>  **1 : 2 / 3**   :   Bosnia-Herzegovina (submission date: 15 February 2016)
>
>  [image: Bosnian-Herzegovinian flag]

And consequently, the next row would look like this:

> **2 : 3 / 5**   :   Serbia (submission date: 22 Dec 2009, 5-coloured flag)
>
>  [image: Serbian flag]

Comment: Ah ok, yes I probably wasn't going to pick up on this without considering G.....a (and I guess I must have calculated the number of colours in M.....a wrongly, else I would have considered that). Sometimes it's hard to change your initial thinking when you've gone so far down a particular thought path already...

Answer (score 6):

<sup>Since it's been 3 weeks, a partial answer to explain the puzzle, without quite being able to spot the intended solution...</sup>

This puzzle has been inspired by another one on this site - namely, [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119698/can-you-solve-this-country-puzzle). The hints all point to this:

> 1. Check its URL - the puzzle can be found at node number 119698 on this very site (i.e. '*inside the house*'). Since *this* puzzle clocks in at node number 119707, it can be found '*nine doors* (i.e. nodes) *down from this one*'.
>
>  2. The creator of that puzzle is PSE user [@Prim3numbah](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63733/prim3numbah) - a corruption of '*prime number*', using a little [*1337*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) (i.e. 'leetspeak' - here with the use of a '3' in place of an 'e') and '*a bit gangstah*' in the use of the 'ah' ending in place of 'er'.

Now *that* puzzle revolved around...

> ...the [**aspect ratios of national flags**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aspect_ratios_of_national_flags) (i.e. the standard proportions of their width and height). And that's again what is involved here. The first part of each row in the puzzle (before the slash) is one of these ratios.

There's another useful clue in the title too...

> There are two capitalised letters in it - 'E' and 'U'. This means we are likely to need to think about **Eu**ropean flags in particular.

And this is confirmed by an observation from the first line:

> There are only two national flags whose standard aspect ratio is 1:1.4 (or 5:7) - Albania and Kosovo, both European.

So what might the numbers *after* the slashes represent? Something that immediately springs to mind...

> ...on looking at these flags is **the [number of colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flags_by_number_of_colors)** used in the flag's design.
>
>  The number after the slash is a '3', and the flag of Kosovo uses 3 colours:
>  [image: Flag of Kosovo]
>
>  (Albania's has just 2 colours, so this would differentiate between them...)

So what does each row represent? I would suggest the following:

> **1 : 1.4 / 3**: Kosovo:
>
>  [image: Flag of Kosovo]
>
>  **2 : 3 / 2 | 1 : 2 / 6**: Two nations (either side of the bar). The first (before the bar) could be Austria, Greece, Turkey or Ukraine:
>
>  [image: Flag of Austria] [image: Flag of Greece] [image: Flag of Turkey] [image: Flag of Ukraine]
>
>  The second (after the bar) is Croatia:
>
>  [image: Flag of Croatia]
>
>  **2 : 3 / 2**: Again, one of Austria, Greece, Turkey or Ukraine (presumably a *different* one):
>
>  [image: Flag of Austria] [image: Flag of Greece] [image: Flag of Turkey] [image: Flag of Ukraine]
>
>  **1 : 2 / 3**: Bosnia-Herzegovina, Hungary, Ireland, or the UK:
>
>  [image: Flag of Bosnia-Herzegovina] [image: Flag of Hungary] [image: Flag of Ireland] [image: Flag of UK]

However, since I have not yet managed to disambiguate these, it is impossible to know what the intention for a 'fifth line' would be. One thing that *may* come into play here is...

> ...differing statuses of [EU membership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlargement_of_the_European_Union), especially since (famously on all 3 counts) Kosovo is currently an applicant, Turkey's application is the subject of a high-profile freeze right now, and the UK is the only nation to have actually left the union. However, I'm not seeing it just yet...

Comment: You are very, very close! Unfortunately, reading your answer, I just noticed a very lamentable typo in the question – a 2 should have been a 3 in the third line! I’ve fixed the question now.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah, ok - I'll alter my answer to reflect the intended wording...

Comment: A hint to the disambiguation: An erroneous assumption has led you to look in a slightly wrong haystack, but you have nonetheless found the exact spot where the correct needle may be found.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are you maybe suggesting that my interpretation of the number that follows the slash is incorrect...?

Comment: Earlier than that, actually!

Comment: If I were to give a hint to your erroneous assumption, it would have to be that [Spoiler!] [Spoiler!] [Spoiler!]. If you get that fixed, I think you will find the correct solution very easily.

Comment: FYI, I’ve now posted the full solution, with details about where your logic went slightly awry.